# css selector to select all elements in Page where specific element exists

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using css media queries in my main css file for printing some page elements. 
Here is the sample code

```
body *
    {
        visibility: hidden;
        background: #FFF;      
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    #Grid *
    {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

But my application is huge and I don't want this to affect the existing functionality. So I only want this css to apply on the pages where **`<Div>`** element with id **`<Grid>`** exists also writing this in other css file and using in each page would be very time consuming as I need this functionality on about **80 pages**.Is there **any way to select all body elements where div with id Grid exits** in a single css file for all the application ? I am  thinking of something like

```
body [div="Grid"] * {}
```

but unfortunately this doesn't works.

Comment: Try `body div#Grid {}` - is this what you intend?

Comment: Wouldn't `#Grid * {}` do it?

Comment: `div[id="Grid"] *`, which is identical to `div#Grid *`, except less-well supported. Are the relevant elements really children of that element though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK selecting parent element using child element is not possible in either CSS2 or CSS3.

But you can do this with CSS4, check [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) for more info :) FYI this is not supported in any of the browsers. But just mentioning the code below

```
body! > div#Grid { 
   background-color:red;
}
```

Here is the fiddle which shows above example http://jsfiddle.net/M75wZ/

But if you are open to third party JS plugins which enables parent selectors, here is a plugin that does the job https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector/blob/master/jQuery.cssParentSelector.js.

But if you just want only for this requirement and want to make it work, do like below

```
 window.onload = function(){
     var div = document.getElementById('Grid');
     if(div){
        if(document.body.className.indexOf('bodyHasGrid') == -1){
           document.body.className += " bodyHasGrid";
        }
     }
 }
```

Then apply styles using `body.bodyHasGrid`

Hope this gives at least an idea of doing it.

Comment: No, CSS 4 supplies the *syntax* for a parent selector, but not the ability to use it in a browser environment: '[fast vs complete selector profiles](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/#profiles).'

Comment: @David Thomas: The unfortunate notion of the existence of a "CSS4" only makes matters worse. The way I see it, Selectors now exists as an independent branch from the rest of the CSS spec, defining a fast profile for CSS implementations, and a complete profile for everyone else.

Comment: @DavidThomas Have a look at this http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject. see selectors overview section last one.

Comment: @Exception: yes. I *know*. What you're missing is that while the Selectors module *defines the syntax* for a subject-selector it explicitly does not allow it to be used in the 'fast profile': "CSS implementations conformant to Selectors Level 4 must use the ‘fast’ profile for CSS selection." (Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#profiles).

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

*any way to select all body elements where div with id Grid exits*

**NOT POSSIBLE WITH CSS** as we don't have parent selector yet, so you cannot select any parent based on child element.

---

Inorder to select the `div` element, having an `id` `Grid`, use the selector below

```
div[id="Grid"] {
  /* Styles goes here */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FgGnu/)

Note: Above selector will select only those elements having an `id` `Grid`, if you expect to target entire page where an element with the `id` `Grid` exist, than you cannot do that.

---

If you want to target elements uniquely which are on a particular page, than call the same `id` on `body` element, and replace `div` with `body` and further nest the element you want to target like

```
body[id="Grid"] div.target_unique {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Comment: Just thinking aloud here... `body:matches(! div#Grid) *` (obviously won't work, ignore)